# Проблема с админ панелью Django

Tags: python, django

Ребят всем привет. Такой вопрос, при создании сайта на Django после создаия superuser словно работа сайта прекращается хотя  не нажимал ctrl+c и нет никакого поля про это. и такое лишь когда хочу зайти в админ панель, все остальные сслыки открываются хорошо. До создания superuser админ панель всегда окрывается. Помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо

Comment: Первое, что приходит в голову: миграции базы данных выполнены?

Comment: я сначала выполнил makemigrations а потом migrate и все равно ничего

Answer (score 0):

Все я разобрался, просто переустановил python и django